# How to render html from a string in a database

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-rendering

I am wanting to create a blog, this blog is for me to record my journey learning to become a software engineer/web developer. I have a separate offline blog uploader where I will create a title and the content and upload it to a database this has two inputs.

1.title

2.post_text

. However I want my blog posts to be able to render custom html for example the output from the database is this `title: Test, post_text:<h1>This is a test!</h1>`

However I have no clue how to render this **HTML**.I tried using `createElement()` and. then adding that to the **DOM** however that wasn't working First step is displaying it on the 'all posts' section in mini cards. Next would be creating the page that will render this detail.

I am using React.js for the blog. Can anyone link me to some help, or can anyone suggest any ideas I could to tackle this issue

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fullstack-react-blog-app-with-express-and-psql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React has [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for exactly this. If you're receiving HTML and you want it to be rendered as HTML (not as a string):

```js
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post_text }} />
```

You should make sure your HTML is coming from a trusted source - in your case, a CMS should be fine.